# How to access td elements using DOM

Tags: javascript

I'm making a script for a webpage, can't use getElementById as tables only have classes so i'm looping through all the td elements.

```
function func(){
alert('Working');

var element = document.getElementsByTagName('td');
var Length = element.length; //740
document.write(Length + "<br />");
var counter = 0;

if(counter < Length){
document.write('Loop Initialized...' + "<br />");
var elementValue = element[counter].firstChild;
var elementType = element[counter].firstChild.nodeType;

if(elementType == 1){
    document.write('Invalid value(1)' + "<br />");
}else if(elementType == 2){
    document.write('Invalid value(2)' + "<br />");
}else if(elementType == 3){
    if(elementValue == 'undefined'){
        document.write('Undefined...' + "<br />");
    }else{
    document.write('***   ' + elementValue + '   ***');
    }
}else{
    alert("An error has occurred.");
}
counter++;
}
}
</script>
```

OUTPUT:

740 
Loop Initialized...

It doesn't even seem to touch the second loop..?

Comment: I don't even see any loops in this.

Comment: Never, never, never use document.write. Use .innerHTML and put your output in a DOM node.

Answer (score 0):

`document.getElementsByTagName` returns a “live” `NodeList`, i.e. changes to the DOM are reflected in it. So if you remove an element from the document `document`, it will be removed from a live `NodeList` obtained via `document.getElementsByTagName`. `document.write` clobbers the entire DOM after the document has been “closed” (parsing has finished), so your list becomes empty as soon as you write your debugging message.

This is what `console.log` is for!

Oh, and as @RevanProdigalKnight says, you don’t actually have a loop, either.